# how to return C++ pointer in objective-C++

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++

I have the following objective-C++ header with the simple method to return this pointer.

```
@interface MyObj
{
  MyCPPObj * cpp;
}
-(MyCPPObj *) getObj;
```

I have created the simple method

```
@implementation MyObj
-(MyCPPObj *) getObj
{
  return cpp;
}
```

Everything seems to work until I actually try to use the object in another file

```
newObj = [createdMyObj getObj];
```

It complains: error: cannot convert 'objc_object*' to 'MyCPPObje *' in initialization.

It seems that the method is return an objective-c object, but I specifically requested a C++ pointer.

MyCPPObj is an honest C++ class:

```
class MyCPPObj
{
 public:
   int x;
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Where is your declaration for `MyCPPObj`?

Comment: `-getObj` is a very bad name for an accessor method. Methods including the word *get* are reserved for methods that return a buffer of bytes. In the example you give, the accessor should be named `-cpp`.

Comment: It's OK to give the accessor a different name than the instance variable, but yes, it should not have `get` if it's not returning something by reference. It should just be `obj` or `cpp` or `cppObj` or something like that. Furthermore, you may want to use `@property` syntax to declare this property. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have forgotten to `#import` the header file with the `@interface` into the .mm file where you use `getObj`.

Answer (score 3):

On my 10.6.3 machine, the following combination worked without any problem: `aho.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
class MyCPPObj{
};
@interface MyObj:NSObject
{
  MyCPPObj * cpp;
}
-(MyCPPObj *) getObj;
@end
```

and `aho.mm`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "aho.h"

void foo(){
    MyObj*objcObj=[[MyObj alloc] init];
    MyCPPObj*cppObj=[objcObj getObj];
}
```

Two pitfalls you might have fallen into:

1. Unlike C++, a class in Objective-C which doesn't inherit from `NSObject` won't work. (Well, you can make it work, but you don't want that usually.) Note the line `@interface MyObj:NSObject`.
2. To use `NSObject`, do `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`
3. Don't forget to use the extension `.mm` for Objective-C++ files.

Answer (score 1):

The error states what happens, and JeremyP is right on the money.  When you forget to include a header file with the prototypes of the selectors, the compiler assumes the selector returns an object of type id.  Well id is a typedef to objc_object*, which is incompatible with your C++ class.  To fix the error, you simply need to include your header file in the file where you called getObj.